# Combine Select and Update statement

Tags: java, sqlite

I have tried to research this problem however I cannot find a solution.
Background:  I have a small java program using sqlite as its DB.  I am trying to update a row counter to keep track of how many time a code is searched, or how many times a row is displayed. (If a row is not displayed it will not be counted). My database table hase three columns {Codes, Description, ItemCount}

Here is code that I used to get a row

```
     private void SrchCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt)               {                                         
   String sql =  "SELECT * FROM emdcodes WHERE Codes like ?"; // SQL command

try {ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setString(1, EMDCODELOOKUP.getText() + "%");        
rs = ps.executeQuery();
ResultsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
} catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }    }
```

I am using this sql code on a website version and it works. it is written in PHP.

```
    $sqlcount = mysql_query("update emdcodes SET ItemCount = ItemCount +1 Where       Codes        like '$term%'");
```

My Question is where and how would I add the counter code to the java progam.  The purpose of the counter is to maintain a list of the top 5 items searched for.

I thank anyone for their help.

Comment: I suggest you create procedure to doing so, it's better, because you have just one call with db, while you approach is talking about two (select, and update) calls, have a procedure that count one and return the value

Comment: I thank you for your suggestion.  If I may ask would you please provide an example or direct me to where I could find out for my self.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what are you looking for...

```
    private void SrchCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt)               { 
       if (counter <= 5)  {                               
       String sql =  "SELECT * FROM emdcodes WHERE Codes like ?"; // SQL command

       try {ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       ps.setString(1, EMDCODELOOKUP.getText() + "%");        
       rs = ps.executeQuery();
       if (rs.first()){
          counter++;
       }
       ResultsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
       } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }    
  }   
}
```

`first()` -> 
Moves the cursor to the first row in this ResultSet object.
Returns:
true if the cursor is on a valid row; false if there are no rows in the result set

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am trying to update a column entry in the table that has that code:                                       my table has three columns, Codes - descriptions - ItemCount.   When user searches for code 1 the jave program deisplays its matching description and SHOULD increment the ItemCount by one.  For example a use searchs for code 1 three times and Code 6 for two times  the column ItemCount next to the row with Code 1 would now be 3  and the ItemCount for Code  would be 2.

Comment: i was also thinking about combining the SQL QUERY to encompass the SELECT and UPDATE statments in one QUERY

Comment: OK here is more code Im Tring            private void SrchCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             
   String sql =  "SELECT * FROM emdcodes WHERE Codes like ?";
    try {ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);    
    ps.setString(1, EMDCODELOOKUP.getText() + "%");        
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ResultsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));    
    ps.executeUpdate("update emdcodes set ItemCount = ItemCount + 1 where Codes like ?"); 
   } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }    }